# How do I selectively consume a message in a RabbitMQ queue

Tags: rabbitmq

I am trying to figure out if this out.  I have form that takes in data from a user.  When the form is submitted I create a unique key for the data is added to the data a message is created and it is sent to the exchange.  The user is then redirected to a thank you page and the unique key is sent with it.  On the thank you page the user has 3 options.  2 links that they can navigate away from, or they could just close the browser window.  When any of these events happen I will send a JSON to another submission with the unique key to decided that the data is ready for processing and how to process it based on their exit from the page.  What I don't understand is if I can consume the queue that the data is in selectively and only take out the message that I want or do I have to consume all the messages?  Do I have to consume the message and decide if it's the processable and if not re-insert it into the queue? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

In RabbitMQ you can't consume a specific message. You always get the message that's on the head of the queue.

Comment: Yeah that's what I've come to figure out, was hoping the route key would help me pick and choose, but I guess not. I'll have to figure out another solution.